# Method of Function Calls in PHP

Tags: php

I have a website in which I have put all my functions inside one page, the page is called functions.php.

For example when I want to delete something from database I use the below method,

code in delete.php

```
< a href="functions.php?delete&id=1 >delete < /a >
```

code in functions.php

```
if(isset($_GET['delete']))  {   delete();   } ---> calls delete function in functions.php
```

Each function is called like above method in functions.php,

My question is: When functions.php page is loaded, does the server loads all the functions or only the called function?

Comment: functions.php is executing on the server, and loads all of the functions

Comment: browser dose not load any PHP files, that's why it's called server-side language.

Comment: `$_GET[delete]`... please note that this is a syntax error; the index name `delete` needs to be wrapped in quotes. (PHP will let you get away with it most of the time, but it is wrong and you will get warning messages)

Comment: sorry, just ignore browser word from my question

Comment: dears, the main question is the last two line, just ignore any mistake from other lines

Comment: Yes, when `functions.php` page is loaded, all the code in the `functions.php` file are loaded in the server's memory.

Comment: so i should not put all functions inside one page because when there are 1000 functions and server loads all functions, it will take much time for server also for browser that waits for server respond, is it right??

Comment: You sound like you've fallen into the [tag:micro-optimization] trap

Comment: It will load the whole functions.php file (with all 1000 functions), but won't execute them (except when the code explicitly calls them), so the time overhead is very slight (nanoseconds).... A better justification for splitting the file isn't performance, it's readability and maintainability of the code

Comment: should i continue using this method or not? any suggestion please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when `functions.php` page is loaded, all the code in the `functions.php` file are loaded in the server's memory. Since you asked for suggestion so, IMO :

In this case (if you think you have a lots of functions in a single file), you can separate the functions in files, i.e. `delete.php` for delete function, `edit.php` for edit function and so on, and use `url` like this, for example, to delete to call `delete` function, you may use a `url` like this

```
<a href="delete.php?id=1 >delete</a>
```

And your `delete.php` file can look like this (it keeps your code more maintainable)

```
function delete($id)
{
    if( is_numeric($id) ) {
        // delete according to $id
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$id = $_GET['id'];
if(isset($id) && delete($id)) {
    // deleted
}
else {
    // not deleted
}
```

This will keep your code clean and more readable and it applies the principle [Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)
But, it won't take too much time to load the single file with so many functions in it, difference is very little.

Answer (score 0):

It's functions are only usable in server side, you that code you wrote is only capable of generating output only